# Calling a method in objective-c extension class in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, extension-methods

How can I use any of the methods which are implemented in an extension in objective-c, and use it in my swift class?
I have a swift class in which I am trying to call a extension method which is implemented in objective-c.

Comment: You can create a share instance of extension class then also you can access method from swift class.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a bridging header file. To create this, go to File -> New -> File -> Objective-C File. Name this file whatever you want, and press next. You can just delete it later.

After pressing next, it will prompt you asking if you would like to configure a bridging header. Press ok.

Inside the bridging header, just add:

```
#import "NameOfYourExtension.h"
```

and it will be available in all of your swift files.

Comment: I have the bridging header file already in and I have imported the extension class also. But still on calling a method inside the extension class, I get "unrecognized selector sent to class"

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add -ObjC in the Other Linker Flags in the build settings for the target. It worked after setting it.